# fetch data from sqlite as an integer using iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How can i fetch the data from sqlite as an integer in iphone technology.
I have fetched the data as a string that code is mentioned below,now what
have to chage in this code by which i can fetch the data as an integer.
Please help me out.

```
databaseName = @"KNAJ.sqlite";

NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
databasePath =[documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];

[self checkAndCreateDatabase];

list1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];  

sqlite3 *database;
if (sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    if(detailStmt == nil)
    {
        ///const char *sql = "Select * from Purch1 ";

        // const char *sql = "select item from purchase order by item desc limit 1 ";


        const char *sql = "select * from product2";         

        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &detailStmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
        {               
            //NSLog(@"Hiiiiiii");
            //sqlite3_bind_text(detailStmt, 1, [t1 UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
            //sqlite3_bind_text(detailStmt, 2, [t2 UTF8String], -2, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
            //sqlite3_bind_int(detailStmt, 3, t3);

            while(sqlite3_step(detailStmt) == SQLITE_ROW) 
            {
                //NSLog(@"Helllloooooo");












                //NSString *item= [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(detailStmt, 0)];


                NSString *item= [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(detailStmt, 0)];


                char *str=( char*)sqlite3_column_text(detailStmt, 0);

                if( str)
                {
                    item = [ NSString stringWithUTF8String:str  ];

                }

                else
                {
                    item= @"";
                }







                //+ (NSString*)stringWithCharsIfNotNull: (char*)item
                /// {
                //  if ( item == NULL )
                //  return nil;
                //else
                //  return [[NSString stringWithUTF8String: item] 
                //stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet: [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
                //}                 









                //NSString *fame= [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(detailStmt, 1)];
                //NSString *cinemax = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(detailStmt, 2)];
                //NSString *big= [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(detailStmt, 3)];

                //pvr1 = pvr;
                item1=item;
                //NSLog(@"%@",item1);

                data = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];   


                list *animal=[[list alloc] initWithName:item1];

                // Add the animal object to the animals Array
                [list1 addObject:animal];
                //[list1 addObject:item];
                NSLog(@"%@",item1);                 
            }
            sqlite3_reset(detailStmt);
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(detailStmt);
        //  sqlite3_clear_bindings(detailStmt);
    }
}
detailStmt = nil;
sqlite3_close(database);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You could probably guess what you need to do given the function name `sqlite3_column_text`...

There is plenty of [documentation on SQLite](http://sqlite.org/c3ref/funclist.html), but the direct answer to your question is use `sqlite3_column_int` or [`sqlite3_column_int64`](http://sqlite.org/c3ref/column_blob.html) depending on the size of integer you need.